# Can I create a folder programmatially in Android 4.x (ICS)?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, directory

Is there an API in Android SDK to create a Folder on the Home Screen in Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.x). You know, a folder where users can then put apps icons and shortcuts inside.

LiveFolders have been deprecated in Honeycomb, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since folders aren't even a requirement for a home app, and there could be arbitrarily many home replacement apps running at once, I'm fairly positive that no, there are no APIs in the Android SDK related to this.

If you can go the route of assuming you know what home app is the default (which you most likely cannot), there may be APIs for a specific home app that could allow for folders to be added.

Comment: Thanks, what you say makes sense. So, only shortcuts and widgets are implemented by all the Home, not folders. So I'm supposed to implement a Folder as a Shortcut or Widget that opens a custom Activity. I can do that. If I do do that, can I intercept the event of users dragging and dropping an icon on top of my shortcut or widget?

Comment: Again, anything that happens in a homescreen replacement app is probably out of your control in the general case. The folder/app dragging and dropping is handled by the homescreen app. Good idea with using a  shortcut to emulate a folder, though. What's the use case for this question anyway?

Comment: I have in mind a tool to automatically put Apps you download in meaningful folders.

Comment: This is one implementation https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abcOrganizer&hl=en

Answer (score -1):

did you try

```
File myDirectory = new File(myDir);
myDirectory.mkdirs();
```

where myDir is a String path

That works fine with me...

for example you can

```
String externalStorageDirectory = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String myDir = externalStorageDirectory + "/MyDirName/";
```

Comment: I meant I Folder on the Home screen, where you can put Apps or Shortcuts inside just by dragging them. Not a folder on disk. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: He's talking about home screen folders. Not file system directories.

Comment: Oh sorry, I overlooked the "homescreen" part